# python ObjectListView has a single un-editable column

Tags: python, wxpython, objectlistview

I have a ObjectListView that I have made editable with

self.TrackOlv.cellEditMode = ObjectListView.CELLEDIT_SINGLECLICK

The gives me 2 odd issues.

1) I can't edit the first cell/column.  Is this due to OLV treating it like a primary key or something to that effect?  I assume I can get around it by creating another attribute to my object and then just not displaying it, but that seems kind of cheesy.

2) I have about 4 chars worth of white space before the first char of my first column.  Is this normal?  This includes the standard blue/yellow line color effect.  I have the white space, then the column text and color effect will begin.  Its not a big deal, just wonder if its normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) For each column have you added isEditable=True?

```
first_col = ColumnDefn('Name', 'left', -1, 'name', isEditable=True)
```

This works perfectly for me in my OLV, along with having;

```
self.TrackOlv.cellEditMode = self.TrackOlv.CELLEDIT_SINGLECLICK
```

2.) You can read why this is the case [here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/faq.html#why-is-the-text-of-the-first-column-indented-by-about-20-pixels). Basically, if you don't need sorting, you can get rid of this gap.